# How to renumber from 1 and increase by 1 for a series of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have numbers like this

`4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4`

I want to change them into

`1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5`, which is renumbered from 1, and with 1 increment, no matter if some number appears again.

So in Python, what is the most efficient way to do this?

It is a series of numbers from my protein PDB residue ID. Each residue has multiple atoms. The pdb also has multiple chains and missing residues, that is why the input number re-start from the beginning at some point and always have some gaps. But I just want the numbers to be 1 increment from 1 to the very last residue.

Comment: please show what you have tried. also: what happens to the sequence `4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 9, 2, 2, 4, 4`?

Comment: "what I have tried"? I do not know how to achieve this.  "What happens to the sequence"? it is a series of numbers from my protein PDB residue ID. Each residue has multiple atoms. But I want to simplify it so not mention the protein stuff.

Comment: from your question it is unclear what the result of the sequence i asked about should be (the first answer gives you a version for both possible interpretations...).

Comment: @lanselibai: so presumably you want to re-use the same number for the same protein PDB residue ID.

Comment: sure, I changed the example, so the 1 increment will also be made.

Comment: Right, so you are renumbering groups of consecutive values, not unique values.

Comment: Code golf of this question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189932/chunk-enumerate-a-list-of-digits

Comment: haha, so this question should be useful, but it is still "on hold".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) together with a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to map unique values to an increasing count:

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(count(1).__next__)
result = [counter[v] for v in inputlist]
```

`count(1)` starts counting at `1` (as opposed to the default starting value of `0`, and the [`__next__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) produces the next value each time the `counter[v]` dictionary lookup uses a value that is not yet in the dictionary:

```
>>> counter = defaultdict(count(1).__next__)
>>> counter["foo"]  # not yet in the dictionary
1
>>> counter["foo"]  # already in the dictionary
1
>>> counter["bar"]  # new value, so a new count is assigned
2
>>> counter
defaultdict(<method-wrapper '__next__' of itertools.count object at 0x10b2a7fc0>, {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> example = [4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2]
>>> counter = defaultdict(count(1).__next__)
>>> [counter[v] for v in example]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

This does assume that if a given number in the input list appears again later on (so not in the same consecutive group) that the number is *reused*:

```
>>> counter_example = [4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>> counter = defaultdict(count(1).__next__)
>>> [counter[v] for v in counter_example]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If that's an issue, then use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) together with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to number groups of consecutive numbers:

```
from itertools import count, groupby

result = [c for c, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(inputlist), 1) for _ in g]
```

Here the starting value of 1 is passed to `enumerate()` as the second argument (`enumerate()`, like `count()`, starts counting at `0` by default).

`groupby()` creates groups where consecutive values are equal, so two runs of `4` separated by other values form two separate groups and they each get a separate count. You do then need to repeat the assigned number as many times as there are values in each group, hence the `for _ in g` loop at the end.

Demo:

```
>>> [c for c, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(example), 1) for _ in g]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
>>> [c for c, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(counter_example), 1) for _ in g]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Note that either solution can be made entirely lazy with `map()` or additional `itertools` functions:

```
# lazy defaultdict lookups

counter = defaultdict(count(1).__next__)
lazy_result = map(counter.__getitem__, inputlist)
```

and

```
# lazy group enumeration

from itertools import chain, repeat

lazy_result = chain.from_iterable(
    repeat(c, sum(1 for _ in g))  # sum() calculates iterator length efficiently
    for c, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(inputlist), 1)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `enumerate` like this

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = [4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2]
>>> [i for i,(_,grp) in enumerate(groupby(lst), 1) for _ in grp ]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: I initially had made the mistake of overcomplicating my `groupby()` with `count()`, then switched to `enumerate()`. I had not yet seen your answer when I did so however! Sorry if that looked like I updated my answer to reflect yours.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. No issues :)